# How do you turn on Hellhounds in Call Of Duty Black Ops 2?

Tags: ps3, call-of-duty-black-ops-2, cod-black-ops-zombies

I have COD: Black Ops 2, and love the zombie map [Town](https://callofduty.fandom.com/wiki/Town). But then I read that you could turn on Hellhounds. How do you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to start up a custom match from the zombies menu, you are still able to invite your friends if you like, but from there after you chose a map you are able to pick a starting round and enable hellhounds.

This can be chosen for both local and multiplayer games.

[This guide](https://au.ign.com/wikis/call-of-duty-black-ops-2/Custom_Zombies) can help you decide how and what to choose.

> Look for the "Custom" option at the online Zombies menu.
>
> - Hellhounds: Want to only fight zombies? Enable or disable the option of Hellhounds.

Comment: How do you do that exactly? And can I still play multiplayer without internet?

Comment: @SkyPaul If by "Mutliplayer" you mean two players sharing the same console; yes. This is still considered "Local". You can also set up a "LAN" where multiple consoles are connected to the same network.

Comment: I just needed to update. :)